# Unable to find image 'gcr.io/fullstackgcp/gradle:latest' locally on Google Cloud Build

Tags: android, docker, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm following this https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/building-android-apk-with-cloud-build-gradle-docker-image to build Android APKs via Cloud build

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/fullstackgcp/gradle:latest' locally
/usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gcr.io/fullstackgcp/gradle, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See '/usr/bin/docker run --help'.
```

Did anyone experience this as well?

Answer (score 1):

This account had been suspended for billing issues (likely because people were all  referring to that image, instead of hosting it themselves); I've already reported that. Meanwhile I've created another one fully working example (without making the same mistake to share the builder image): [`cloudbuild-android`](https://github.com/syslogic/cloudbuild-android), which is just as good, if not a tad better.

Full disclosure: I've wrote that builder, because of the problem with the image.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error. Digging deeper I figured that you first need to prepare a Docker image that will build your Android app and upload that image to Google Cloud Registry. To do that I used: [Cloud Builders Community](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/android):

1. Checkout their repository
2. Go to `cloud-builders-community/android/`
3. Trigger CloudBuild to build & upload a docker for you (specify the Android SDK version you need):

`gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml --substitutions=_ANDROID_VERSION=28`

At this point you should be able to use `gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/android:28` instead of `gcr.io/fullstackgcp/gradle` in the cloudbuild definition provided in the tutorial.

**However** I decided not to risk and hit the next error, so I used [this one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/master/android/examples/simple-cloudbuild.yaml) (provided by Cloud Builders Community again). They do have a step for caching the gradle build so you would also need a `tar` docker:

4. Go to `cloud-builders-community/tar/` and run:

`gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml`

After all of this is done you can build your app by running the following in the app folder:

`gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml --substitutions=_ARTIFACT_BUCKET=<your_bucket>,_CACHE_BUCKET=<your_bucket>`

The trigger you have already created as part of the tutorial will also work. You just need to add the two variables above: `_ARTIFACT_BUCKET` and `_CACHE_BUCKET`

Comment: Thanks @vladimir, after I built my own image I got this permission issue


```
    Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/[$project-name]/android:28
    No .buildenv file found at /
    /bin/sh: 1: ./gradlew: Permission denied
```

Comment: I am getting the same permission issue. Any idea @Vladimir?